# How to wrap all content elements?

Tags: typo3

I have content elements with different types in a column. One possible type i.e. is a gridelement. So i.e. I have a column colPos=0 with these elements:

```
- Header
- Text&Media
- Text&Media
- Gridelement
    - Text&Media
    - Text&Media
```

What I expect as result should be:

```
<div class="col_0">
   <div class="row"><h1>Header</h1></div>
   <div class="row">[Text & Media]</div>
   <div class="row">[Text & Media]</div>
   <div class="row gridelement">
       <div class="col_1">[Text & Media]</div>
       <div class="col_2">[Text & Media]</div>        
   </div>
</div>
```

So every content element should be wrapped in a div with class="row". But only if they are not in a grid element column.

Comment: Are you using the fluid_styled_content extension? Can you post the template you are using for textmedia elements?

Comment: Yes, I use it with default templates.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding here. "What I expect as result should be:" - is this really what you expect should happen or is this what you want to happen?

Comment: In this backend layout is one column. In this column can be content elements and gridelements placed. Now I need content elements directly in the column (colPos >= 0) should be wrapped in `<div class="row">|</div>`. If a content element is inside a grid cell (colPos = -1) then thay should not be wrapped.